# SDG override generated queries

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-gemfire, geode

Stack: Geode 9.1, SDG 2.0
Scenario: We have a scenario where temporary regions are created(snapshotted) on the fly and would like to leverage the SDG queries to use these new region instead of the defined regions. 
Question;
Is there a hook-point to override the region name post the proxy invocation so we can superimpose the temp-region name instead of the defined region for the SDG repository?

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there a hook-point to override the Region name post the proxy invocation so we can superimpose the temp Region name instead of the defined Region for the SDG Repository?*

Well, yes, there are hook-points (per say) in several areas of SD's *Repository* infrastructure where you could accomplish this, but it (specifically, SDG) was not intentionally designed with this purpose in mind, so it is a bit involved.

As you know, you enable SDG *Repositories* using the SDG [`@EnableGemfireRepositories`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/repository/config/EnableGemfireRepositories.html) annotation on your *Spring* application `@Configuration` class, like so..

```
@Configuration
@EnableGemfireRepositories(..)
class ApplicationGemFireConfiguration { .. }
```

Effectively, the "proxy" created by the SD *Repository* infrastructure for your application-specific, SD *Repository* interface extension is backed by a default implementation provided by the data store-specific (e.g. GemFire) SD module (e.g. SDG).

1 way in which this default implementation is determined is by the [`repositoryBaseClass`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/repository/config/EnableGemfireRepositories.html#repositoryBaseClass--) attribute on the annotation.  As you can see, it defaults to [`o.s.d.g.repository.support.SimpleGemfireRepository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/repository/support/SimpleGemfireRepository.html).

Internally, SD's *Repository* infrastructure, and specifically SDG, creates an instance of the SDG `SimpleGemfireRepository` class to back the proxy in order to implement the basic CRUD and query operations defined on SD `CrudRepository` interface (so developers do not have to; a developer just need declare additional, application-specific query methods).

The `SimpleGemfireRepository` class [expects](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/repository/support/SimpleGemfireRepository.html#SimpleGemfireRepository-org.springframework.data.gemfire.GemfireTemplate-org.springframework.data.repository.core.EntityInformation-) an instance of [`o.s.d.g.GemfireTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/GemfireTemplate.html) along with `EntityInformation` about the application domain object type that is being persisted (handled) by the application SD *Repository*.  As you know, this is defined by the application-specific SD *Repository*, like so...

```
interface CustomerRepository extends GemfireRepository<Customer, Long> { .. }
```

The application domain object type (i.e. entity class; e.g. "`Customer`") typically determines the *Region* in which the objects of that type are persisted/accessed (i.e. [mapped](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.entities))...

```
@Region("Customers")
class Customer .. { .. }
```

It is this mapping meta-data (i.e. `@Region("Customers")`) that is [used by the SD[G] *Repository* infrastructure/extension](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/2.0.0.RC2/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/repository/support/GemfireRepositoryFactory.java#L109-L115) by default to determine the GemFire *Region* in which the entity is mapped.  It would have been a bit easier if I have made the "resolution" of the *Region* [7](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/2.0.0.RC2/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/repository/support/GemfireRepositoryFactory.java#L109-L115) configurable, such as with a pluggable *Strategy* interface, something like "`RegionResolver`" (I may consider this).

It is also possible to override the *Region* on the application *Repository* interface itself; for instance, in addition to the `CustomersRepository` above, you can...

```
@Region("VIPS")
interface VipCustomerRepository extends CustomersRepository { .. }
```

Again, see "[*POJO mapping meta-data*](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.entities)" for more information.

Since `SimpleGemfireRepository` delegates to the `GemfireTemplate` to perform all *Region* data access operations, it is really the `GemfireTemplate` that references the *Region* used by the repo.  As you can [see](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/GemfireTemplate.html#GemfireTemplate-com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.Region-), the `GemfireTemplate` takes a reference to the *Region* on which the data access operations, including "queries", are performed.  Again the *Region* was determine by the SD[G] Repo infrastructure in [7](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/2.0.0.RC2/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/repository/support/GemfireRepositoryFactory.java#L109-L115).

So, how can you use this knowledge to, I gather determine the Region "dynamically" at Runtime, since you creating "temporary" *Regions* as such.

Well, you could provide your own implementing class (in place of SDG's `SimpleGemfireRepository`), like so...

```
@Configuration
@EnableGemfireRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = DynamicRegionGemfireRepository.class)
class ApplicationGemFireConfiguration { .. }
```

You must still define a constructor that accepts the `GemfireTemplate` and `EntityInformation` as before, [in SDG's `SimpleGemfireRepository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/repository/support/SimpleGemfireRepository.html#SimpleGemfireRepository-org.springframework.data.gemfire.GemfireTemplate-org.springframework.data.repository.core.EntityInformation-) class...

```
class DynamicRegionGemfireRepository<T, ID> extends SimpleGemFireRepository<T, ID {

    DynamicRegionGemfireRepository(GemfireTemplate gemfireTemplate, EntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation) {

        super(new DyanmicRegionGemfireTemplate(gemfireTemplate, entityInformation), entityInformation);
    }
}
```

Once you get the reference to the `GemfireTemplate`, you could wrap it or replace it with your own implementation as well, such as...

```
class DynamicRegionGemfireTemplate<T, ID> extends GemfireTemplate {

  private final EntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation;

  private final Region<?, T> primaryRegion;

  DynamicRegionGemfireTemplate(GemfireTemplate gemfireTemplate, EntityInformation entityInformation) {

    this.primaryRegion = gemfireTemplate.getRegion();
  }

  // override Region<?,?> getRegion() here

}
```

Now, you override the [`getRegion()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/GemfireAccessor.html#getRegion--) method on `GemfireTemplate` (technically, the [`o.s.d.g.GemfireAccessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/GemfireAccessor.html), which `GemfireTemplate` extends).

```
@Override
public Region<K, V> getRegion() {

    // logically determine the "temporary" Region to use, 
    // perhaps using the EntityInformation, or else just return 
    // the primary Region if no temporary Region exists.

  return primaryRegion;
}
```

Something like this... make sense?

There are other ways you can accomplish this as well.

Anyway, hope this helps!

Regards,
John

Comment: Thanks John! This helps. We have been able to override the region-name for regions using SimpleGemfireRepository (e.g findOne, findAll). But the custom repository methods defined for each of the repository are not invoking the DynamicRegionGemfireTemplate.getRegion() – @EnableGemfireRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = DynamicRegionGemfireRepository.class, basePackages = {"com.test.repo"})

Comment: Submitted PR - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/pull/93

The Travis-ci is not green - not sure of the reason,, can you help?